# preg_replace href if url inside href does not contain particular domain

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, href

I need to remove `<a href` from text, except if domain/url in href contains `example.com`

I have found this regex, but it replaces right now all urls `(.*?)` , any ideas how to make it so it replaces all hrefs **except** if url contains `example.com`

`preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $_POST['desc']);`

Here is example how the replace should work

`<a href="http://example.com/test">test1</a>    ==> Should not be replaced (targeted)
<a href="http://google.com/test">test2</a>      ==> test2`

Answer (score -1):

```
['"]https?:\/\/(?!example\.com)[^"']+['"]
```

That regex will match all URLs exept those whose domain is `example.com`
In this case i'm asuming it may be encapsulated either between single quotes or double quotes, say `href="{url}"` or `href='{url}'`.

Comment: Thanks, with bit edit it works fine https://regex101.com/r/qZ8tD3/4